# how to deal with numbers with `u''` in python?

Tags: python, unicode

I'm using NetworkX to read some data. The data format is like u`1`, u`12`. For example, in the library, there is a list:

```
networkx_lista = [u'1', u'3', u'12'].
```

Now I want to search for u`3`, but I only have an integer c=3.

Is there a function that can convert `c` into u'3'? Like:

```
networkx_lista.search(unicode(c))
```

I tried `chr()` and `unichr()`, it seems they produce only `'\x03'` or `u'\x03'`, not u`3`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The data is represented as strings, not numbers. The `u` simply means that it's an unicode string. Try this:

```
'3' in [u'1', u'3', u'12']
=> True
```

As you can see, I'm treating the number `3` as a string `'3'`. Alternatively, you can convert the input list of strings into a list of integers:

```
networkx_lista = [u'1', u'3', u'12']
networkx_lista = [int(x) for x in networkx_lista]
```

Now you can directly search for integer values in the list:

```
3 in networkx_lista
=> True
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't have numbers; you have unicode strings. Convert your strings to numbers with `int()`, or your integer number to a unicode string.

`unicode()` will do fine for the latter approach, as does `str()` as Python will automatically encode / decode values to compare byte strings and Unicode values.

You can use `any()` or `in` membership testing here:

```
any(int(v) == c for v in networkx_lista)
```

or

```
unicode(c) in networkx_lista
str(c) in networkx_lista
```

If you don't *need* the list to be unicode strings, you can always convert the list to hold integers instead, once, and be done with it:

```
networkx_lista = [int(x) for x in networkx_lista]
```

and save yourself the trouble of having to convert either `c` or the contents each time you need to test membership.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert int to string and search it in list. For example, the follwing piece of code will print 'True'

```
num = 3
print str(num) in networkx_lista
```